# Determining Last Cell Used and Inserting Formula in Different Column

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get a vba code that determines the last row used in column A then inserting the following formulas in the stated columns until the last row.

```
Range("AC2:AC" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF($S2="""",""Discard"",$T2-8)"
Range("AD2:AD" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF($S2="""",""Discard"",($S2*1000000000000)/($AC2*10000000))"
```

Hoping to do this without referencing the worksheet name.
Thanks for any help!

Edit: What I am trying to figure out is the last row used in Column A. Then have the above formulas inserted in columns AC and AD from row 2 to the determined last row. I hope this clarifies what I am asking.

Comment: [This is a very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/5936117). The rest of your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified last row using

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Then modified my formulas to this:

```
Range("AC2:AC" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF($S2="""",""Discard"",$T2-8)"
```

And it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rows.count property of the sheet, which will give you the maximum row used (in any column) then go up from that in Column A, some pseudo code below

```
lastRow = range("A" & sheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row
```

Comment: This only answer partially the question.

Comment: it does? I believe that the formula part works, the OP was just having problems identifying the last row, which does seem to be clarified in his edit

Comment: Jpad-When I tried using your code above I encountered an error. Can't recall what it was at this time. Thanks for the help though!